# Will IBM Lotus Notes Application can be accessed through Microsoft Visual Studio ?

Tags: .net, console-application, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm creating an utility for checking the application status either working or not. Well I'm having an windows console application in C# .NET which use Lotus Notes Domino dll and Lotus Notes Client Password to access Lotus Notes Application. Is there any other way to access the lotus notes application without any dependency of IBM lotus notes or Its password ?. Please provide me some suggestion or idea to solve this issue

Comment: One possible alternative technique could be to try to create an LDAP connection to the Domino server.

Comment: Checking via an LDAP connection would only tell you whether the server is responding on the LDAP port. It does not guarantee that the server is responding to Notes client requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prove that a Domino server is responding to Lotus Notes client connections, you have to use NRPC (port 1352) to connect to it. The only way to do this is through the Lotus Notes core DLLs, and this requires a Lotus Notes client installation and ID file.  (This is true even if the Domino server is configured to accept anonymous connections.)

If you can live with a lower level of assurance, then you could make a connection via LDAP, HTTP, IIOP or SMTP - presuming that the Domino is configured to run any of those services. This will at least prove that the server is up, but there would still be a small possibility that it is not accepting connections from Notes Clients.

The last thing I want to mention is that just connecting to the server is not enough to prove that the application is fully available. You would at least have to open the NSF file(s) that are associated with the application.

Comment: Hi Richard, I have tried this approach which is mentioned this
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18517/Lotus-Notes-Integration-with-Microsoft-NET-Platfor) In this approach they are initializing the notes session with a password But Is it possible to access the lotus notes nsf file without the password

Comment: Notes and Domino are a very secure system. There are no back doors to get you access without proper credentials. That API uses the Notes Core DLLs. Those DLLs  require a Notes ID. If corporate security policy allow it, you could remove the password from the ID file, bit this is not a good idea - and you still need the ID.